# How can I access the bit representation of a file using Scheme?

Tags: io, scheme

If I had a file called raw_text.txt, is there a way I could iterate through each bit?

I see the following but am confused on how to use it:

http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/File-Manipulation.html
— procedure: file-attributes/mode-string attributes
The mode string of the file, a newly allocated string showing the file's mode bits. Under unix, this string is in unix format. Under Windows, this string shows the standard “DOS” attributes in their usual format.

EDIT: I am using mit-scheme

Comment: The "bits" mentioned in `file-attributes/mode-string` refer to the file permissions, not its actual contents

Comment: I'm a bit confused (no pun intended!) by your question - do you need to read the characters in the file, one by one, or the actual 1's and 0's that define each character in the file? is it a binary file or a text file? if it is a text file, knowing its encoding is relevant

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I want to be able to go through the actual 1s and 0s that define each character in the file regardless of file type, whether its an mp3 or odt, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's implementation-specific.  On the Racket side of things, there are a few libraries:

1. http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=bitsyntax.plt&owner=tonyg
2. http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=bit-io.plt&owner=soegaard

You can probably use something like the binary-parse library as well: http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/binary-io.html, as long as your implementation of Scheme can support it.

Under MIT Scheme, you can use the [bit-string](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.5/7.5.17/doc-html/scheme_10.html) functions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am using MIT-scheme, and will look through the binary parse libraries soon.

Comment: The binary parse library was not exactly what I was looking for [unless I missed something in it!]. It does not have anything to read or write bits [0s and 1s] to file. I am going to repost this question with a bit more info.

Comment: Revising answer: under MIT Scheme, there's a set of functions on bit-strings, which may be what you're looking for.  You can read bytes from a file, and use the **unsigned-integer->bit-string** to turn each into a bit-string.  I'm not sure if there's a convenience function already available to turn the whole contents of a file into a single bit-string, but it shouldn't be too bad to code if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried to do anything with this, but I think you're looking for this section of the mit-scheme docs: [Input/Output](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput).  Specifically the file ports and input procedures sections.

I didn't see anything specifically about reading the binary bits, but if it's character bytes you want, it looks like there are procedures for that.  Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
(call-with-input-file "raw_text.txt" <procedure>)
```

or

```
(call-with-binary-file "raw_text.txt" <procedure>)
```

Where `<procedure>` will take the file port and use the input procedures to read things from that file.

Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do?

EDIT:  It appears that someone did a write up on this [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/binary-io.html).

Comment: I want to take a list of integers such as: (1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0) and basically write the integers to file as bits, if that makes sense. I tried those commands, the procedure I used was read-char and it failed to bring up binary files. Perhaps I am using the wrong proc, but I couldn't find one for reading bits. Thanks for your response though.